# Cannot Convert Custom ExpyTableView Type in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, protocols, custom-component

I'm working on an iOS application using Swift and encountered a type mismatch error when trying to use ExpyTableView, an expandable table view library. The error occurs in a part of my code where I'm attempting to manipulate the expandable sections of the table view.

```
import UIKit
import ExpyTableView

open class ExpyTableView: UITableView {
    
    fileprivate weak var expyDataSource: ExpyTableViewDataSource?
    fileprivate weak var expyDelegate: ExpyTableViewDelegate?
    
    public fileprivate(set) var expandedSections: [Int: Bool] = [:]
    
      open var expandingAnimation: UITableView.RowAnimation = ExpyTableViewDefaultValues.expandingAnimation
      open var collapsingAnimation: UITableView.RowAnimation = ExpyTableViewDefaultValues.collapsingAnimation
    
      public override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
    }
    
    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    open override var dataSource: UITableViewDataSource? {
        
        get { return super.dataSource }
        
        set(dataSource) {
            guard let dataSource = dataSource else { return }
            expyDataSource = dataSource as? ExpyTableViewDataSource
            super.dataSource = self
        }
    }
    
    open override var delegate: UITableViewDelegate? {
        
        get { return super.delegate }
        
        set(delegate) {
            guard let delegate = delegate else { return }
            expyDelegate = delegate as? ExpyTableViewDelegate
            super.delegate = self
        }
    }
    
    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        if expyDelegate == nil {
            //Set UITableViewDelegate even if ExpyTableViewDelegate is nil. Because we are getting callbacks here in didSelectRowAtIndexPath UITableViewDelegate method.
            super.delegate = self
        }
    }
}

extension ExpyTableView {
    public func expand(_ section: Int) {
        animate(with: .expand, forSection: section)
    }
    
    public func collapse(_ section: Int) {
        animate(with: .collapse, forSection: section)
    }
    
    private func animate(with type: ExpyActionType, forSection section: Int) {
        guard canExpand(section) else { return }
        
        let sectionIsExpanded = didExpand(section)
        
        //If section is visible and action type is expand, OR, If section is not visible and action type is collapse, return.
        if ((type == .expand) && (sectionIsExpanded)) || ((type == .collapse) && (!sectionIsExpanded)) { return }
        
        assign(section, asExpanded: (type == .expand))
        startAnimating(self, with: type, forSection: section)
    }
    
    private func startAnimating(_ tableView: ExpyTableView, with type: ExpyActionType, forSection section: Int) {
    
        let headerCell = (self.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)))
        let headerCellConformant = headerCell as? ExpyTableViewHeaderCell
        
        CATransaction.begin()
        headerCell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        
        //Inform the delegates here.
        headerCellConformant?.changeState((type == .expand ? .willExpand : .willCollapse), cellReuseStatus: false)
        expyDelegate?.tableView(tableView, expyState: (type == .expand ? .willExpand : .willCollapse), changeForSection: section)

        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            //Inform the delegates here.
            headerCellConformant?.changeState((type == .expand ? .didExpand : .didCollapse), cellReuseStatus: false)
            
            self.expyDelegate?.tableView(tableView, expyState: (type == .expand ? .didExpand : .didCollapse), changeForSection: section)
            headerCell?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        
        self.beginUpdates()
        
        //Don't insert or delete anything if section has only 1 cell.
        if let sectionRowCount = expyDataSource?.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section), sectionRowCount > 1 {
            
            var indexesToProcess: [IndexPath] = []
            
            //Start from 1, because 0 is the header cell.
            for row in 1..<sectionRowCount {
                indexesToProcess.append(IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
            }
            
            //Expand means inserting rows, collapse means deleting rows.
            if type == .expand {
                self.insertRows(at: indexesToProcess, with: expandingAnimation)
            }else if type == .collapse {
                self.deleteRows(at: indexesToProcess, with: collapsingAnimation)
            }
        }
        self.endUpdates()
        
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
}

extension ExpyTableView: UITableViewDataSource {
    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let numberOfRows = expyDataSource?.tableView(self, numberOfRowsInSection: section) ?? 0
        
        guard canExpand(section) else { return numberOfRows }
        guard numberOfRows != 0 else { return 0 }
        
        return didExpand(section) ? numberOfRows : 1
    }
    
    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard canExpand(indexPath.section), indexPath.row == 0 else {
            return expyDataSource!.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
        }
        
        let headerCell = expyDataSource!.tableView(self, expandableCellForSection: indexPath.section)
        
        guard let headerCellConformant = headerCell as? ExpyTableViewHeaderCell else {
            return headerCell
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if self.didExpand(indexPath.section) {
                headerCellConformant.changeState(.willExpand, cellReuseStatus: true)
                headerCellConformant.changeState(.didExpand, cellReuseStatus: true)
            }else {
                headerCellConformant.changeState(.willCollapse, cellReuseStatus: true)
                headerCellConformant.changeState(.didCollapse, cellReuseStatus: true)
            }
        }
        return headerCell
    }
}

extension ExpyTableView: UITableViewDelegate {
    
    open func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        expyDelegate?.tableView?(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        
        guard canExpand(indexPath.section), indexPath.row == 0 else { return }
        didExpand(indexPath.section) ? collapse(indexPath.section) : expand(indexPath.section)
    }
}

//MARK: Helper Methods

extension ExpyTableView {
    fileprivate func canExpand(_ section: Int) -> Bool {
        //If canExpandSections delegate method is not implemented, it defaults to true.
        return expyDataSource?.tableView(self, canExpandSection: section) ?? ExpyTableViewDefaultValues.expandableStatus
    }
    
    fileprivate func didExpand(_ section: Int) -> Bool {
        return expandedSections[section] ?? false
    }
    
    fileprivate func assign(_ section: Int, asExpanded: Bool) {
        expandedSections[section] = asExpanded
    }
}

//MARK: Protocol Helper
extension ExpyTableView {
    fileprivate func verifyProtocol(_ aProtocol: Protocol, contains aSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
        return protocol_getMethodDescription(aProtocol, aSelector, true, true).name != nil || protocol_getMethodDescription(aProtocol, aSelector, false, true).name != nil
    }
    
    override open func responds(to aSelector: Selector!) -> Bool {
        if verifyProtocol(UITableViewDataSource.self, contains: aSelector) {
            return (super.responds(to: aSelector)) || (expyDataSource?.responds(to: aSelector) ?? false)
            
        }else if verifyProtocol(UITableViewDelegate.self, contains: aSelector) {
            return (super.responds(to: aSelector)) || (expyDelegate?.responds(to: aSelector) ?? false)
        }
        return super.responds(to: aSelector)
    }
    
    override open func forwardingTarget(for aSelector: Selector!) -> Any? {
        if verifyProtocol(UITableViewDataSource.self, contains: aSelector) {
            return expyDataSource
            
        }else if verifyProtocol(UITableViewDelegate.self, contains: aSelector) {
            return expyDelegate
        }
        return super.forwardingTarget(for: aSelector)
    }
}
```

What I've Tried:

1. Ensuring that there are no naming conflicts with the ExpyTableView library.
2. Checking if the custom subclass and the library's class are being correctly referenced in different parts of the project.
3. Verifying that all imports are correctly set up and that there are no circular dependencies.

**What I Was Expecting:**

I expected to seamlessly integrate my custom subclass with the ExpyTableView library's functionality, allowing for expandable sections within my table view without any type mismatch errors.

**Question:**

How can I resolve this type mismatch error and ensure that my subclass works correctly with the ExpyTableView library? Is there a way to avoid this conflict between the custom subclass and the library's class name?

Answer (score 0):

You have imported ExpyTableView in your code and you are trying to declare a new ExpyTableView, therefore you get invalid redeclaration error.

if you want to customize ExpyTableView you need to create a new sub-class of ExpyTableView:

```
class CustomTableView: ExpyTableView {
    // override methods and properties you want to change
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate this a bit further? like where am i trying to declare a new ExpyTableView(which i should delete?) and where should i change the code to make this work.

Comment: In the code snippet have included in your original post, you have imported ExpyTableView and also declared a new ExpyTableView class.